# Populate a newly added calculated column in EntityFramework Core + npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have added a column to a database table that is calculated from the values of other columns. It is never set directly but is updated when those columns are updated.

I have achieved this in my model class without any raw SQL and it works fine with one issue: I want the migration, when applied, to populate this column for all rows, without having to wait for each field to be updated manually after a change.

A simplified example of the model would be like:

```cs
public class MyModel 
{
  private string _title;
  private string _description;
  private string _data;

  public string Title
  {
    get 
    {
      return _title;
    }
    set
    {
      _title = value;
      UpdateCombinedField(value, _description, _data);
    }
  }

  public string Description
  {
    get 
    {
      return _description;
    }
    set
    {
      _description = value;
      UpdateCombinedField(_title, value, _data);
    }
  }

  [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
  public string Data
  {
    get
    {
      return _data;
    }
    set
    {
      _data = value;
      UpdateCombinedField(_title, _description, _value);
    }
  }

  public string CombinedField { get; set; }

  public void UpdateCombinedField(title, description)
  {
    // some logic here extracts string values from json e.g. { k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2' } -> 'v1 v2'
    CombinedField = title + " " + description + " " + extractedJsonValues;
  }
}
```

The idea is to create a single text field which can be searched - unfortunately the [npgsql SearchVector option](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html) did not work due to the binary nature of jsonb. So instead `UpdateCombinedField` creates a string of that field which can be concatenated with the other string fields into `CombinedField`.

As I say this works OK, the issue is getting `CombinedField` to populate when the migration is applied.

I tried using the following in the Migration's `Up` method, which is adapted from the SearchVector guide above where it is used to cause an update of the table:

`migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE \"MyModels\" SET \"Title\" = \"Title\";");`

But I'm not sure how to set a trigger that causes the above code to work, without having to take the code that calculates the combined column out of the class and into SQL - so running into the jsonb binary issue again.

We are using postgresql 10.

To summarize the requirements, what is needed is combine the text columns and the values from the jsonb column into a single text column, that also runs for the existing rows when the migration is first applied. This column being a Tsvector is a bonus, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to understand exactly what you're doing.

PostgreSQL 10 does not support calculated columns, although this feature is coming with PostgreSQL 12 - see [this issue and the links contained within](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/939). This feature will probably be quite useful for what you seem to want.

In any case, you could have a text column that contains a text copy of your jsonb column (updated via a trigger), which can then be used in a tsvector column. However, JSON data really *isn't* text, and doing full-text search on it might not work as you expect.

> migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE \"MyModels\" SET \"Title\" = \"Title\";");

Have you set up a trigger as described in the documentation page? This code only serves to make the trigger run for the first time after creation.

Comment: I have altered the question slightly to try and clarify the goal. I think the option of having an additional text copy of the jsonb column to then use in a tsvector would work, provided it would be possible to create a trigger that takes only the string values of the jsonb into the new column e.g. { k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2', k3: true, k4: ['v2', 123]} becomes 'v1 v2'. 

I have the logic to do that currently in UpdateCombinedField - I imagine it is not easily done in SQL which is why I wanted somehow to be able to trigger UpdateCombinedField c# method for all rows when the database is first updated

Comment: It should be quite easy to extract specific values from your jsonb column and concatenate them together into a text, something like `some_json->>'A' || some_json->>'b'`. Otherwise, if you just want to have an additional column in the database that is a concatenation of the others, define a new CLR property with a getter that concatenates, and map that to some column with EF Core.

Comment: The issue with the extraction is that each row of the jsonb column could have an entirely different structure, so it would be required that some trigger could take any jsonb field and extract the string values into a concatenated string in a generic way

Comment: If each row of jsonb can have a completely different structure, how can you have a c# method doing concatenation on that same data? At the end of the day you have to define which days you want to search for...

Comment: A recursive method takes a dynamic object of the deserialized json, loops through the keys / values recursively and ultimately returns a list of tokens which are all the string values from the object, which are joined together delimited by a space by UpdateCombinedField. So ultimately if we have rows 'title: t1, description: d1, json: {k1: 'v1', {k2: 'v2'}}' and 'title: t2, description: d2, json: {k1: ['v1']} - the two rows of CombinedText are 't1 d1 v1 v2' and 't2 d2 v1' - so we can then search 'v1' on that column and retrieve both rows

Comment: That seems quite... elaborate... In any case, as I wrote above, you can always define a property in C# whose getter does whatever you want, and map that to the database as a separate column. This way you get a plain text column in the database, and assuming all updates are done from EF Core it will always reflect the other values as you wish. Its setter can be a noop so that when EF Core loads the entity from the database it will be ignored.

Comment: I managed to get a combination of my additional JsonValues column from the c# property, + SearchVector column using that column along with my other text column (as per the npgsql full text search guide). My remaining issue is now that trying to use the .Where(e => e.SearchVector.Matches(query)) causes me a System.NotSupportedException. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Which version of the provider are you using? If it's 3.0.0 preview8 it may be a dup of https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/978. If not an issue would be great (with a code sample and a stack trace), I'll look into it.